# Como formatar o dia da semana para não aparecer símbolo no PHP

Tags: php, data, codificação-de-caracteres

Como trocar o símbolo **�** que aparece em Terça-feira por um **Ç**?

[image: Ter�a-feira 22/08/2017 - bem vindo(a),]

**Meu código abaixo:**

```
<?php 
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese" );
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    echo ucwords(strftime("%A "));
    $dt = date('d/m/Y', time());
    echo $dt;
?>
```

Comment: Você deve alterar o Encoding do site de ASCII para UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neste caso, basta chamar a função [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)

Ficando assim:

```
echo ucwords(utf8_encode(strftime("%A ")));
```

Comment: obrigado! funcionou!

Comment: @RobertoAlexandreDaSilva Se essa resposta solucionou o seu problema e não lhe restam mais dúvidas acerca disso, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ ao lado dela. Isso também marcará a sua pergunta como resolvida/solucionada.